# Caret in R: Set number of cores for allowParallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am using R's caret package, and in the training function (train) I use the allowParallel Parameter, which works. However, it uses all of the cores, and since the training runs on my local PC I would rather leave one core for myself to be able to work while training models. Is there any way to do this?

From what I've gathered it seems that different model types might use different parallelization packages. I am working on windows, so I guess it's not using doMC (where I know how to set the number of cores...)

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/pml-randomForestPerformance.md

Comment: I tried it, but this seems to be specific for randomforest only. With method="ranger" (which I use) it just uses all 8 cores...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after more research, I found a way to use the number of cores I want: train has the option to directly specify the number of cores to use with `num.threads = 7` (for 7 out of 8 cores)

```
rf_model<-train(Target~., data = df_tree_train, method = "ranger",
                trControl = trainControl(method = "oob"
                                       , verboseIter  = TRUE
                                       , allowParallel = TRUE
                                       , classProbs = TRUE
                )
                , verbose = T
                , tuneGrid = tuneGrid
                , num.trees = 50
                , num.threads = 7  # <- This one
)
```

Comment: worked only after added doFuture from @HenrikB answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that:

```
library("doParallel")
registerParallel(parallel::detectCores() - 1)
```

does not do it.  Maybe there is recursive parallelism that does not acknowledge the above.  You could try with the [doFuture](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) package:

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()
plan(multisession, workers = availableCores() - 1)
```

EDIT: 2022-01-29: The 'multiprocess' backend is deprecated, in favor of 'multisession'.  If you want *forked* parallel processing, use 'multicore'.
which should protected against unwanted nested parallelism.

Comment: doFuture lib helped for caret::train